# Derivation of the integral form of the numerator in the Bayesian inference equation???? (not on the denominator)

Tags: statistics, bayesian, neural-networks, gaussian

In the reference *Gaussian processes: iterative sparse approximations* by Csató, Lehel
(Csató, Lehel. Gaussian processes: iterative sparse approximations. Diss. Aston University, 2002), on page 20, chapter 2

- *Csató, Lehel*, [**Sparse on-line
  Gaussian processes : iterative sparse
  approximations**](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Lehel-Csato/publication/40498273_Gaussian_Processes_-_Iterative_Sparse_Approximations/links/0c960523af9bf61526000000/Gaussian-Processes-Iterative-Sparse-Approximations.pdf),
  Diss., Aston University (2002).

  From Baysian law, the posterior distribution is given as, using
  $\boldsymbol{f}_D = {f(x_1),...,f(x_N)}$ for the random variables at
  the data positions,    $$ p_{post}(\boldsymbol{f}) = \frac {
     P(D|\boldsymbol{f})p_0(\boldsymbol{f})} {    \langle
     P(D|\boldsymbol{f}_D) \rangle_0}\\
     =\frac { \int P(D|\boldsymbol{f})p_0(\boldsymbol{f}, \boldsymbol{f}_D)d\boldsymbol{f}_D} {    \langle
     P(D|\boldsymbol{f}_D) \rangle_0}$$

where $p_0(\boldsymbol{f},\boldsymbol{f}_D)$ is the joint Gaussian distribution of the random variables at the training and sample locations, $<P(D|\boldsymbol{f}_D)_0>$ is the average of the likelihood with respect to the prior GP marginal, $P_0(\boldsymbol{f})$.

How did the author calculate the numerator of the integral form ($\int P(D|\boldsymbol{f})p_0(\boldsymbol{f}, \boldsymbol{f}_D)d\boldsymbol{f}_D$ ) from ordinary Bayesian law?

Did anyone see a similar form in the statistics society?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably $p_0(\boldsymbol{f}) =  \int p_0(\boldsymbol{f}, \boldsymbol{f}_D)\,d\boldsymbol{f}_D$ and all they have done is  moved $P(D|\boldsymbol{f})$ inside  $\int \cdots d\boldsymbol{f}_D$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood your comment :)